# set persian language to data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I want to add sorting for persian language in my table. I use this data table

https://datatables.net

I added this plugin for sort my table

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/persian

Here is my html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="persian.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery -->


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // $('#example').dataTable();
    $('#example').DataTable( {
       columnDefs: [{ type: "pstring" , targets: 0 }
        ]
     } );


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>هوشیار</td>
                <td>برنامه نویس</td>
                <td>تست</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>میلاد</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>پدر</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>



        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed the configuration in those links, but it didn't work and it did not sort some persian words like "گ چ پ ژ".

help me through this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I added this script to my html file and it worked. I think even though I added the persian file below the datatable.js , it did not load after that!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var persianSort = ['آ', 'ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ي', 'ي'];
            function GetUniCode(source) {
                source = $.trim(source);
                var result = '';
                var i, index;
                for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                    //Check and fix IE indexOf bug
                    if (!Array.indexOf) {
                        index = jQuery.inArray(source.charAt(i), persianSort);
                    } else {
                        index = persianSort.indexOf(source.charAt(i));
                    }
                    if (index < 0) {
                        index = source.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    if (index < 10) {
                        index = '0' + index;
                    }
                    result += '00' + index;
                }

                return 'a' + result;
            }
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                "pstring-pre": function (a) {
                    return GetUniCode(a.toLowerCase());
                },

                "pstring-asc": function (a, b) {
                    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
                },

                "pstring-desc": function (a, b) {
                    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
                }
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the `persian.js` file before `jquery.dataTables.min.js`.  This is a problem because `persian.js` depends on `jquery.dataTables.min.js`.

Error:

```
persian.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oSort' of undefined
    at persian.js:45
    at persian.js:59
```

As you can see on line 45,

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
```

`persian.js` looks for the property `oSort` on the object `jQuery.fn.dataTableExt`, but it isn't there.

Place the persian file after the data table one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="persian.js"></script>
```

[Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s12twf5j/1/)

Comment: I've added a fiddle. Let me know if that isn't the desired outcome.

Comment: actually client can choose the ordering, in fiddle it is only descending and client can not change the ordering by selecting each column subject in the table head.

Comment: @mhtb Oh yeah, my bad.  I wasn't including resources correctly.  JSFiddle has the <head> resources included from the "External Resources" Tab on the left.  This is the same order that the resources should be loaded.  Try moving persian.js above the datatables.  You will see that the table output is no longer in order.

Comment: I tried to put persian. js above the datatables and it did not work,  also tried to put it below the datatables and it did not work! finally I added a script above my html and it worked.